# Trigger a function only one time after press a button - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, timer

i want to start a function after 5 seconds when i press the button just one time ,
for this i use [Timer Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html), but when i put it on initState, it start whitout clicking on  button,

This is my code :

https://www.dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b

```
Timer time;

  @override
  void initState() {        
    super.initState();

    _time = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) {
       print('yaaay');      
       t.cancel();
    });    

  }

  void start() {    
    _time ;   
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,

        children : [

           ElevatedButton(
             child:Text('press me'),             

             onPressed:(){
               start();
             }
          ),
        ]);    
     );
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Trigger it in the `onPressed` property of your button. For instance:

```
 onPressed:(){

 Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:5)).whenComplete((){
  start();
  }); 

 }
```

Comment: it didn't work, because it trigger every time i press the button, but i want it to be just one time only.

Comment: use a variable to check if the button is pressed for the first time or not

Comment: declare bool pressed=false; and then onpressed set pressed=true; using setstate then surround the Future.delayed code by this condition if(pressed==false){//Future.delayed code....}else{start();}

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you not putting it in the `initState` method, because that means it will always trigger when this widgets initiates its state, that is

> when this object is inserted into the tree

From: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html

And that's why this functions is being triggered "automatically". Instead just place your function where you can manually trigger it. For instance, inside the `onPress` property of your button, since you said that's what you're trying to achieve ;). @biruk IS's solution seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you're using the following code:

```
_time = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) {
  print('yaaay');      
  t.cancel();
});
```

it means you're `creating` a Timer and `run` it.

So, if you want to start the timer when clicking the button, you need to modify your code like the following:

```
void _startTimer() {
    _time = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) {
      print('yaaay');      
      t.cancel();
    });  
}

void _stopTimer() {
   if(_time != null) _time.cancel();
}
```

then use it on your button:

```
ElevatedButton(
    child:Text('press me'),             

      onPressed:(){
        _startTimer();
      }
),
```

Comment: it didn't work, because it trigger every time i press the button, but i want it to be just one time only. (like the other solution)